# sphinx-apidoc -F -o <output_dir> <project_dir> failing to create make file:

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

I'm attempting to use Sphinx to document a Python library I've been working on. I've been using [this post](http://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/) as a rough guide along the way. But, I'm having issues getting Sphinx to work correctly.

Once everything is set up, Sphinx has been installed, and I've added documentation to my code I enter from the root of my project:

```
sphinx-apidoc -F -o docs/ mypackage/
```

Output:

```
Creating file docs/mypackage.rst.
Creating file docs/mypackage.helpers.rst.
Creating file docs/conf.py.
Creating file docs/index.rst.
Creating file docs/Makefile.
Creating file docs/make.bat.
```

Next, I edit docs/conf.py respectively ensuring that my sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/Users//path/to/mypackage')) is correct.

However, when I attempt to build the docs (from within the docs directory) via:

```
build html
```

I am greeted with:

```
-bash: make: command not found
```

I've used sphinx-apidoc and make html with other libraries and never ran into this so I'm sort of at a loss. Any thoughts?

Comment: Install `make` with your distribution's package manager.

Comment: @Blender you were %100 correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Blender stated in the comments. `make` was not installed. I recently had to reinstall Xcode and forgot to reinstall the *command line tools*.

For clarification, I am running OSX 10.8.5.

To use `make` first install `Xcode` via the `app store` and then open Xcode and download/install the `Command Line Tools` by navigating to: `Xcode->Preferences->Downloads`